# Get rid of few commits

Tags: git, github

This is my log of github's master branch:

```
---newest commits---
dfnjk35 - I dont want theese changes
fsdjk5k - I dont want theese changes
sdfnjk5 - ok
zchnjk4 - ok
jqwio75 - I dont want theese changes
dsfnk51 - I dont want theese changes
asnmm12 - ok
hfgaut1 - ok
zxdfsd2 - ok
---oldest commits---
```

How can I get rid of changes that I do not want? I want to have state from `asnmm12` and `zchnjk4` and `sdfnjk5`. I don't want to mess this up more, so I please for help.

Comment: Have you published this branch and/or is this branch shared by users other than yourself?

Comment: This is master branch published on github. Its shared by users.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your branch is already published on GitHub, rewriting history is basically off the table.  In this case, I would advise using `git revert` to functionally undo the commits you don't want:

```
git revert dsfnk51
git revert jqwio75
git revert fsdjk5k
git revert dfnjk35
```

These commands will create four *new* commits on the top of your branch which will functionally undo what the commits did.  Note that using interactive rebase here is probably *not* advisable, as rewriting the history of a shared public branch can cause havoc for anyone else who shares it.

Note that you may get conflicts from doing a `git revert`.  If that happens, you'll have to resolve the conflicts, `git add` the files which were in conflict, and then `git commit`.  I am also assuming that there are no merge commits in the range you showed us above.

Comment: I am getting error: 
`error: could not revert dsfnk51... hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'`

Comment: @dafie You may get merge conflicts after doing a `git revert`.  You'll have to resolve them, then add and commit.

Comment: But I can't see no merge conflicts in git bash terminal. I have to check every possible file to find conflicts?

Comment: Just type `git status` and it should walk you through it.

Comment: I can see that there are 2 unmerged paths. 
`Content/file1` (I want file 1), `Content/file2` (I dont want file 2). Whats now?

Comment: Don't `git add` the addition of the file you don't want.  You're really asking a different question here.  If you need help with resolving merge conflicts, Stack Overflow can probably help you.

Comment: Every time I use `git revert` I am having conflicts. I don't really know why. Do I really have to deal with every file with conflict? Why Can't I force git to revert changes without solving conflicts?

Comment: @dafie The thing is, you are still rewriting history when you revert something, and therefore there is the chance of conflicts.  If you rebased, the same thing could have happened.  If you want to avoid this, then don't rewrite history in the future, or at least try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use Git's interactive rebase feature, it's great.

`git rebase -i COMMIT-ID` will open an editor and ask you to choose what to do with each commit since COMMIT-ID. You can choose to squash multiple commits together, or remove them entirely (which might affect whether later commits apply cleanly, so you might have to do some conflict resolution).

So run `git rebase -i zxdfsd2` and in the editor you can just delete the lines for the commits you don't want, and Git will recreate the branch without those commits.

An alternative would be to create a new branch, cherry-pick the commits you want onto that branch, then once it's in the state you want, reset `master` to be the same as that branch.

In both these cases, you are rewriting history, so be **very very** cautious about doing that if the branch has been published anywhere and is in use by anybody else (if you go ahead and rewrite history anybody who has fetched the old history will need to reset their local branch to re-sync with the rewritten history).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch from master and cherry pick commits you want to new branch using git cherry-pick command